# How to disable page guide in textwrangler?

Tags: textwrangler

The page guide in text-wrangler is very distracting and I want to disable it. I compare this tool with textpad , are there any standard , compiled list of settings that I could use? How to disable the annoying page guide?

-MS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable Page Guide deselecting "Show Page Guide" in the Text Options, from the Toolbar.

[image: Textwrangler Toolbar]